# Commnads to the applications Command line prompt using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

please find the code

```
atmel_cmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Extensions\Application\StudioCommandPrompt.exe"
subprocess.call([atmel_cmd, 'atprogram' , 'help'])
```

i am unable to send the arguments **'atprogram'** to the application.whenever i run the above script i see only application launching without the parameters.

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing the dashes? `--atprogram` `--help`?

Comment: it doesn't works with the dashes,i have given the right commands.